# Cray aprun is adding an extra dash to program arguments - how can I stop this?

Tags: mpi, cray

I have an MPI application which has a command line option `-ss` to specify an argument. I've been running this successfully on various Cray machines, including ARCHER (www.archer.ac.uk) an XC30, for years. The OS was recently upgraded and as part of this ALPS was upgraded to version 5.1.1-2.0501.8507.1.1

Now when I launch the program on the compute nodes with `aprun`, the program is receiving the the option as `--ss`.

Checking with a shell script instead of a full application

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $*
```

confirms that this option is getting double-dashed by `aprun`.

Clearly there is a bug in `aprun` (I've reported it) but how can I work around the issue until this is patched?

Comment: Does `aprun -aprun -options -- yourprogram -ss youroption ...` work? The `--` forces GNU getopt to terminate the scanning of the argument list. I've seen it also adopted by some non-GNU applications.

Comment: My bad, `--` is not (or no longer) a GNU extension - it is part of the POSIX specification of `getopt(3)`.

Comment: I believe that `aprun` is a Cray developed closed source tool. I did try the `--` end of options option (even thought it's not mentioned in the man pages) and it didn't work.

Comment: Then I guess a temporary solution is to write a wrapper script that replaces every `--` on the command line with `-`.